# call unmanaged C++ code from C# using pinvoke

Tags: dllimport

I have a unmanaged C++ dll for which I do not have access to code but have all methods declarations for.

Lets for simplicity say that .h looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef NUMERIC_LIBRARY
#define NUMERIC_LIBRARY

class Numeric
{
    public:
        Numeric();
        int Add(int a, int b);
        ~Numeric();
};

#endif
```

and method implementation in .cpp file

```
int Numeric::Add(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

I simply want to call the add function from C++ in my C# code:

```
namespace UnmanagedTester
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"C:\CPP and CSharp Project\UnmanagedNumeric\Debug\numeric.dll", EntryPoint = "Add")]
        public static extern int Add(int a, int b);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sum = Add(2, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);

        }
    }
}
```

After trying to execute I have the following error:

Unable to find an entry point named 'Add' in DLL 'C:\CPP and CSharp Project\UnmanagedNumeric\Debug\numeric.dll'.

I CAN NOT change C++ code. Have no idea what is going wrong.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: isn't the method a member of a class?  Not in the public namespace?

Comment: I'm not an expert on unmanaged code in C#, but I assume that since Add is a method inside Numeric, you'll most likely need to make an instance of Numeric and call the method on that instance. If it were static then perhaps your approach would have worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using PInvoke you can only call global functions exported from Dll. To use exported C++ classes, you need to write C++/CLI wrapper. This is C++/CLI Class Library project, which exposes pure .NET interface, internally it is linked to unmanaged C++ Dll, instantiates a class from this Dll and calls its methods.

Edit: you can start from this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx#A8

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I thought that I can simply call a method from a class using dllimport, looks like I was wrong. I will take a look into C++/CLI wrapper. Alex can you advice any online tutorial for that kind of project? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create a wrapper, take a look at [swig.org](http://www.swig.org/). It will generate one for most high level language like C#.

I just came across this program a few minutes ago while working the same problem that you are.

Answer (score 2):

To use a class from native C++ from C# you need a C++/CLi wrapper in between, as mentioned by by previous answers.  To actually do that, it is not very straight forward.  Here is I link that tell you how to do it at a high level: [C++/CLI wrapper for native C++ to use as reference in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223186/c-cli-wrapper-for-native-c-to-use-as-reference-in-c-sharp?answertab=votes#tab-top).

If you are quite new to this (like me), you might stumble on 1) -- the linking part.  To solve that, you can see how I did here (see my question portion):  [Link error linking from managed to unmanaged C++ despite linking to .lib file with exported symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531695/link-error-linking-from-managed-to-unmanaged-c-despite-linking-to-lib-file-wi)