# How to use VC++ application in C#.net desktop application

Tags: c#, api, visual-c++

I have one API that was developed in VC++ and use that API in my C# desktop application. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: There's more than one way to do this, your question is far too vague to recommend the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider wrapping the C++ API in C++/CLI then you will be able to call it from C#.

There are some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223186/c-cli-wrapper-for-native-c-to-use-as-reference-in-c-sharp)

In essence, for a native class define in NativeClass.h you can use it in a C++/CLI project as follows:

```
#include "NativeClass.h"

public ref class NativeClassWrapper {
    NativeClass* m_nativeClass;
};
```