# How to write C# wrapper for libssh2

Tags: c#, libssh2

We are planning to write C# wrapper for libssh2. I have following questions:

1) Since libssh2 is implemented in C/C++. How can I include a C++ dll in my C# project?

2) How can I get handle to the **Session** object of libssh2 in my C# project?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, did you have progress about your wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C# you can call C-Method via p/Invoke and DLL-Import. So if you want to use a c++ library, you have to write a procedural c-wrapper.
Here an example for dll-import:

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 public extern static void Sleep(uint msec);
```

That is how you hae to export the c functions:

```
_declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Function1(void);
```

I would recommend that you read the following tutorial: [Tutorial p/Invoke](http://manski.net/2012/05/pinvoke-tutorial-basics-part-1/)

The second solution is you write a C++/CLI wrapper, but this is much more complex:
[C++/CLI wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223186/c-cli-wrapper-for-native-c-to-use-as-reference-in-c-sharp)