# Calling c struct in C#. Cannot marshal field '***' of type '***'

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I get a c project named Clib2CS with two files which are Clib2CS.c and Clib2CS.h.

Clib2CS.h is as following:

```
__declspec(dllexport) typedef struct BTreeNode {
     int value;
     struct BTreeNode* left;
     struct BTreeNode* right;
 }BTnode;

__declspec(dllexport) unsigned long ConnectSession(unsigned long   handle,
     unsigned char * publicKey,
     unsigned char   publicKeyLen);


__declspec(dllexport) void bulidTree(BTnode* root, int value);
```

Clib2CS.c is as following:

```
#include "Clib2CS.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned unsigned long ConnectSession(unsigned long   handle,
                               unsigned char * publicKey,
                               unsigned char   publicKeyLen)
{
         return 42;
}


void bulidTree(BTnode* root, int value) {
    if (root == NULL) {
       BTnode* node = (BTnode*)malloc(sizeof(BTnode));
       node->value = value;
    }
    if (value < root->value) bulidTree(root->left, value);
    else bulidTree(root->right, value);
 }
```

This c project generates a Clib2CS.dll which will be called in a c-sharp project.
The c# project contains only one file named Program.cs.

Progarm.cs is as following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class BTnode {
    public int value;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public BTnode left;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public BTnode right;
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("Clib2CS.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe static extern UInt32 ConnectSession(UInt32 handle, char* publickey, char publicKeyLen);

    [DllImport("Clib2CS.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    unsafe static extern void bulidTree([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] BTnode root, int value);


    public unsafe static UInt32 GetConnectSession(UInt32 handle, string publickey, char publicKeyLen) {
        // "Convert" string to char*
        char* pubKey;
        fixed (char* bptr = publickey) {
            pubKey = (char*)bptr;
        }
        return ConnectSession(handle, pubKey, publicKeyLen);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        UInt32 ret =  GetConnectSession((UInt32)1, "helloworld", 'c');
        Console.WriteLine("####################: {0}", ret);

        BTnode root = new BTnode();
        root.value = 666;
        Console.WriteLine("value of root is : {0}", root.value);

        int[] vec = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        foreach (int item in vec) {
            bulidTree(root, item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");
        for (; root != null; root = root.right) {
            Console.WriteLine("the tree node is: {0}", root.value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Run it, and I get this error:

> Unhandled Exception:System.TypeLoadException: Cannot marshal field 'left' of
>       type 'ConsoleApplication1.BTnode': There is no marshaling support for  this  type.

so, how do we invoke c struct of DLL from c# gracefully?

Comment: From what I remember pointer types equivalence in C# is `IntPtr`, Have you tried with it?

Comment: @m.rogalski yeah, I try it, and it doesn't work. I get error as `The * or -> operator must be applied to a pointer`.

Comment: Equivalent of `unsigned char` in C# is `byte` so this `unsigned unsigned long ConnectSession(unsigned long   handle, unsigned char * publicKey, unsigned char   publicKeyLen)` in C# will be `UInt32 ConnectSession(UInt32 handle, IntPtr publicKey, byte publicKeyLen)`

Comment: Yeah, the `ConnectSession` works well, but it's not the problem. Actually, I am confused on how to call `BTreeNode` in c#. As question says, how to invoke c struct in c#.
Thanks, m.rogalski.

Answer (score 0):

You're too close.
I suggest you to use this for string conversion.

```
String managedString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) (char *) myUnmanagedString);
```

You have to know that `char*` in `c#` and in `c` are different a char in `c` is in 1 byte and in `c#` in 2 bytes so the pointer are not the same.

Your question is a little generale.

1. The first way is to marshall like you did in your first attempt.
2. The second way is to create a `CLI C++ DLL` use your library or your        DLL code as you did in this `C` project and because it's `C++` so it's easy to use with your `C` code and `C#` both because of its nature to handle managed and unmanaged code as result  it will like a normal `.net dll` all you have to do is to add it like a reference so i suggest to take a look to this article for more information:

   - [Quick C++/CLI - Learn C++/CLI in less than 10 minutes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes)
   - [C++/CLI wrapper for native C++ to use as reference in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223186/c-cli-wrapper-for-native-c-to-use-as-reference-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Actually, I am confused on how to call the `BTreeNode` struct not `string and char*`. I will take a look to these articles you linked.
Thanks, @Esperadoce

Comment: @yuan any time.